# Synchronise the entries of one table with another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanted the entries from my table "station" to be automatically copied in my table "arrival_station". Every time when I create a new station in my station table, this new station should be copied/created in my arrival_station table too and when I delete a station, it'll be deleted in my arrival_station table too.
Can anyboy tell me how und where to solve this issue?
e.g.

```
station      arrival_station
---------    ---------
 id           id
 name     =>  name
 shortcut =>  shortcut
```

Here is my schema.rb:

```
create_table "stations", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "shortcut"
t.string   "name"
end

create_table "arrival_stations", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.string   "shortcut"
t.integer "station_id"
end
```

my station controller:

```
 class StationsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_station, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

   def index
     @stations = Station.all
   end

   def show
     @station =Station.find(params[:id])

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html # show.html.erb
       format.json { render json: @station }
     end
   end

   def new
     @station= Station.new
  end


   def edit
   end

   def create
     @station = Station.new(station_params)

     respond_to do |format|
       if @station.save
         format.html { redirect_to @station, notice: 'Station wurde      erfolgreich erstellt.' }
         format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @station }

       else
         format.html { render :new }
         format.json { render json: @station.errors, status:      :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
   end

   def update
     @station = Station.find(params[:id])

     respond_to do |format|
       if @station.update(station_params)
         format.html { redirect_to @station, notice: 'Station wurde      erfolgreich aktualisiert.' }
         format.json { respond_with_bip(@station)}
       else
         format.html { render :edit }
         format.json { render json: @station.errors, status:      :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
   end

   def destroy
     @station = Station.find(params[:id])

     @station.destroy
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to stations_url, notice: 'Station wurde      erfolgreich gelöscht.' }
       format.json { head :no_content }
     end
   end

   private

       @station = Station.find(params[:id])
     end

   def station_params
     params.require(:station).permit(:shortcut, :name)
   end
 end
```

and my models:

```
  class Station < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :arrival_stations, :dependent => :destroy

    before_save
    validates :name, presence: true, length:{ maximum: 255 },
              uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates_format_of :name, :with =>  /\A[a-zA-Z,Ä,ä,Ü,ü,Ö,ö]+\z/i, :message       => "darf nur aus Buchstaben bestehen."
    validates :shortcut, presence: true, length: { maximum: 3 , minimum: 2 },
              uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates_format_of :shortcut, :with =>  /\A[a-zA-Z,Ä,ä,Ü,ü,Ö,ö]+\z/i,       :message => "darf nur aus Buchstaben bestehen."
  end

  class ArrivalStation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :station
  end
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a bad idea. There are very few good reasons to have one table duplicate the data of another. What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your models, a station has_many arrival_stations and yet they all have the same name?  Are you sure this shouldn't be has_one?  Also, it is almost never a good idea to store data in two places which must remain identical.  Most likely better to do something like:

```
@arrival_station.station.name
```

But regardless of those choices...

You can certainly create a child record at the time the parent is created and set the value for the name and or shortcut.

```
class Station < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :arrival_stations, :dependent => :destroy

  before_create :build_arrival_station
  validates :name, presence: true, length:{ maximum: 255 },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates_format_of :name, :with =>  /\A[a-zA-Z,Ä,ä,Ü,ü,Ö,ö]+\z/i, :message       => "darf nur aus Buchstaben bestehen."
  validates :shortcut, presence: true, length: { maximum: 3 , minimum: 2 },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates_format_of :shortcut, :with =>  /\A[a-zA-Z,Ä,ä,Ü,ü,Ö,ö]+\z/i,       :message => "darf nur aus Buchstaben bestehen."

  private
  def build_arrival_station
    arrival_stations.build(name: self.name)
  end
end
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you!!